# Is it possibly to modify a function in memory?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Basically, I have a binary file that I want to patch, I don't just want to invoke a hook on this function, but rather I want to jump right into it and add my own line of codes, modifying some other values too.

For example: say this very simple function is in a binary, but I can't access it, I can only look up for some signature, or an offset if it's a member function of some class etc..

```
void Test()
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 15;

   cout << a << endl;
}
```

I want to change it into this for example:

```
void Test()
{
   int a = 20;
   int b = 15;

   cout << a + b << endl;
}
```

Without having to recreate the entire function, because in my real case.. the function is really complex and requires dozens of other functions that I will have to sig scan too, and most importantly, it is constantly updated.

Comment: I've never done this, but it should be possible, check out these two articles:https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-asia-02/Clowes/bh-asia-02-clowes.pdf and https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v2-pages-245-254.pdf

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible. Practically, not so much. You will have to decompile the code to assembly, and add your logic there.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a debugger for this. edb for linux, and ollydbg for windows are free to use debuggers. Search and modify something like `mov [esp+0x8], 10` to `20`, Or directly modify the stack values :) . In this image https://i.imgur.com/Br3BGnj.png I am modifying the line highlighted in the background with edb debugger.

Comment: @Revolver right, I meant the binary file in the question.

Comment: "I have a binary file that I want to patch,"  Perhaps you may be looking for patching / patch management ideas or tools?  from wikipedia: "A patch is a set of changes to a computer program or its supporting data designed to update, fix, or improve it. This includes fixing security vulnerabilities and other bugs, with such patches usually being called bugfixes or bug fixes, and improving the usability or performance."    Binary patches are typically distributed as executable files instead of source code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is indeed possible to modify functions in memory, this is called 'self-modifying code'. That said however it is extremely complex and doesn't lend itself well to a clean codebase.

What you would instead want to solve this with is a function pointer, this allows you to pass various functions into your existing function:

```
void Test(int (*stringFunction)(int a, int b))
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 15;

   cout << stringFunction(a,b) << endl;
}
```

you could then call your function like so in order to get different behaviour:

```
int defaultFunction(int a, int b) {
   return a;
}
int specialFunction(int a, int b) {
   return a+b;
}
Test(defaultFunction);
Test(specialFunction);
```

Comment: It's not my function to control, I'm trying to edit the server binary of some game

Comment: @Amine You may be on the road to breaking a contract and/or doing something illegal.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that.. there's an entire forums thats been up for the last 15+ years just for these stuff, we work with Source and GoldSource games developed by VALVe, they gave us the SDK but it doesn't help much because it's pretty old and the game gets weekly updates. and they've allowed us to do that with no problems, except that they're shipping binaries with no symbols because of hackers in the client-side of things

Answer (score 1):

Consider hotpatching. My library, if using Windows (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043089/HotPatching-Deep-Inside) could help.

There are many methods that cannot be discussed here in depth, but generally you replace the starting bytes that are dummy bytes (xor rdi,rdi) with your jump code, after telling the linker to reserve these bytes for the function.